# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, backend

Hello i have problem with creating role in my db. The error is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')

role model:

```
const {sequelize, DataTypes} = require('sequelize')
```

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

```
const role = sequelize.define("role",{

    roleTitle: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
    },
}
)
return role
```

}

add role func:

```
const db= require('../models')
```

const Role = db.roles

const addRole = async (req, res) => {

```
let info = {
    roleTitle : req.query.roleTitle,
    description : req.query.description,
    status : req.query.status
}
const exrole = await Role.findOne({ where: { roleTitle : 'title' }})
// if(exuser == null){
    const role = await Role.create({
        roleTitle : "okkk",
        description : 'info.description',
        status : false

    }
  
        )
    res.status(200).send(user)
    console.log(user)
// }else{
//     res.status(404).send({erorr : '404'})
}
```

module.exports = {
addRole
}

Comment: i solve the problem! i should pass the **{sequelize, DataTypes}** in my addRole fuc file

Answer (score 0):

You `return role` and try to access `db.roles`. Change to `db.role` and it should pass this error

Comment: the roles i try to access is roles model file!

Comment: it doesn't matter what's the name of the file, it matters what you return from there, and in your code I see that you `return role`

Comment: i solve the problem! i should pass the **{sequelize, DataTypes}** in my addRole fuc file